# Reopen my question that has several correct answers

Tags: support, code-golf, specific-question

[Shortest Konami Code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/102618/shortest-konami-code-implementation)
I have this question and for some reason it was closed as unclear what I was asking for a second time. I fixed it the first time and it become open. Several correct answers were posted and I accepted one (More about that later). Then a few days ago my question was put on hold as unclear. Can it get reopened?

Also what do you do when you have a answer and you make it accepted. Then you get a better answer (shorter as this is code golf)?

Comment: what have you done to remedy this? Questions are not  closed for no reason.  if you have improved understanding and clarity in some way, we can probably help you.

Comment: For the 2nd time nothing as even redstarcoder can't find what is wrong. Nothing I can see is unclear and I have not gotten anything in feedback from the flaggers.

Comment: @tuskiomi Look at the revision history on the challenge. I think you'll find that some improvements have been made. OP just needs clarity on what problems still need to be fixed.

Comment: @Rainbolt ah, so there have been improvements. I think I can look over them and decide.

Comment: I think it would help if a mod cleaned up the comments that have obviously been addressed, leaving only those that are still an issue.

Comment: I just want to point out the question had issues raised, they were fixed, the question was closed **after** the raised issues got fixed, the question got re-opened, and it got closed again with no new issues raised. So regardless if questions aren't closed for no reason, it's still very true that OP wasn't given any by the time he created this meta post. This should **never** happen, especially not to new members. It really hurts the fun of the place.

Comment: @redstarcoder That's not true. The question was still unclear whether it should be `BABA` or `BA` at the end. (The question said `BABA`, but the [real Konami code only has `BA` at the end](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konami_Code)). Also, the other input/output requirements were still vague.

Comment: @mbomb007 I think the input requirement of `BABA` was clear, as it was defined in the question explicitly so, but especially as all the other answers used `BABA`. I think raising the issue of what the Konami code actually is, is what created any uncertainty. I found the input/output requirements clear, but my point is, I didn't see any of the closevoters saying they found the input/output requirements unclear before. We should be helping and encouraging new members, not slamming them with two closes and 24 hours + a meta post later they get some feedback, that's all I'm trying to say.

Comment: @redstarcoder Closing is not "slamming". It simply makes it so that no new answers may be posted, thus giving the OP more time to fix his question according to the comments. If they had read the comments and provided fixes, they wouldn't have had two closes.

Comment: I read the comments @mbomb007 and fixed it. So please stop saying that I didn't fix it according to comments

Comment: @ChristopherPeart I voted to close in the queue, and no, you hadn't fixed everything. You had said things like "I don't care which" and you weren't specific on the output. See the answer below.

Comment: It was fixed by the time you posted the comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Err... no.

[You should work on improving your challenge first.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges)

Your question is quite unclear, and fairly poorly formatted. By marking it as "On Hold", we signify to future users that challenges which aren't clear will be put on hold, and to further encourage the use of the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges). You were suggested to use the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) [six minutes after](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/102618/shortest-konami-code-implementation#comment249452_102618) the challenge was issued, and it should have been closed at that time rather than later. Please post the question *in* the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges), get some editing assistance, then apply the sandboxed edits to the current question when the challenge is satisfactorily clear and formatted.

As for your second question, please see [this question](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193/when-to-accept-answers) for information on when to accept and what to do when a shorter answer is submitted.

Below are my suggested edits (which may be copied by editing this question and copying the source below the separator line):

---

## Shortest Konami Code

[keyboard](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyboard)[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)[parsing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parsing)

## The Problem

You must write a program that, when the Konami Code is typed in during runtime, prints the string "`+30 lives`" and sounds a noise of your choice from the computer's speaker.

### Definition

The "Konami Code" is defined as `UUDDLRLRBA` followed by pressing the enter key.

### The Rules

- You may choose to use the up arrow for `U`, down for `D`, left for `L`, and right for `R`, as long as your code is consistent with either arrows or letters.
- Your input may be accepted from a controller or a keyboard, but does not need to support both.

Comment: For reference, the question *is* currently [in the Sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/10851/42963). The question in the Sandbox doesn't match the current state of the question on Main, though.

Comment: While the sandbox is a good idea in many cases, I don't think asking here is *inappropriate* at all.

Comment: @Geobits But it would cause a large comment thread (or answers pertaining to a question which should be in the sandbox) that _would_ be. I will remove the comment.

Comment: Well sorry if my formatting is not the best. That was my first question here.

Comment: @VoteToClose Asking about a challenge *before* it's posted is one thing, but asking for specific reasons why it was closed on main is one of the things meta is specifically for. There's even a [tag for it](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specific-question).

Comment: @Geobits I swear I've seen questions like this forwarded to the sandbox before.

Comment: I also got no feedback on sandbox. So I gave up on that and just edited my main

Comment: @ChristopherPeart For future reference, when copying from main to post to  the sandbox, you should delete the main temporarily, then edited and reopened when the sandbox post has been thoroughly reviewed. Even then, Sandbox posts should be left for at least a few days for further review.

Comment: This is much better. I cleaned up my earlier comments.

Comment: Re "*noise of your choice*", see Pavel's comment on the original question.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Adjusted to better match the question.

Comment: @ChristopherPeart People have lives in real life. You can't post in the Sandbox and expect a ton of feedback instantly. You need to be patient and wait a few days.

Comment: @VoteToClose I can't edit your post.

Comment: @ChristopherPeart If you're satisfied with this version, I can copy it in for you.

Comment: @VoteToClose I will do one edit. Just to make it BABA to avoid disqualification of answers

Comment: Nevermind. I will go and inform all the people who answered. And can you open the question back up?

Comment: @ChristopherPeart Not on my own. I already submitted a reopen vote, however.